# How to customize "Other Places" in "My Computer" view for WinXP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

When I open "My Computer" view, there are three sections in the left side - System Task, Other Places and Details, and there are "My Documents", "My Computer" and "My Network Places" in the "Other Places" section, can I add one more link in "Other Places" to point to a specific folder like E:\?

I tried to modify group policy, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft issued a program called 'TweakUI'; one of this program's options allows the definition of specific, custom places.

[image]

Comment: The Places Bar in the Windows File/Open dialog is not the same thing as the Common Tasks Bar in Windows Explorer. This is not the answer to this question.